# Multiple binomial tests in one code

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply, hypothesis-test

I would like to perform the exact binomial test, with `binom` R package(`binom.test` function), to 4 different number of successes with 4 different probability values.

I can do it singularly, but I would like to know if I can write a code to do the calculation in only one command (e.g. lapply, for loop).

```
x <- c(68, 69, 70, 75)  #number of successes
p <- c(1/365, 2/365, 3/365, 4/365)  #probability of success
n <- 265 #number of trials
```

The `conf.level = 0.95` and `alternative = "two.sided"` (as the outcome can be as 1 or 0).

Any suggestion?

---

I tried:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
     test[i] <- binom.test(x[i], n, p[i], alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95)
      }
```

but doesn't work.

Comment: `Vectorize(binom.test)(x, n, p)[3, ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mapply`:

```
mapply(binom.test, x, p, n=n, alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

mapply just calls the function in its first argument with all the values in its additional arguments and additional named parameters. (See help for the mapply function)

If you want just one field of the result, you could call mapply like this:

```
mapply(function(x,p,n, ...){
         binom.test(x, n, p, ...)$p.value
       },
       x, p, n=n, alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested only in the resulting p-values, here is what you can do:

```
x <- c(68, 69, 70, 75)  #number of successes
p <- c(1/365, 2/365, 3/365, 4/365)  #probability of success
n <- 265 #number of trials
test <- numeric(4)

for (i in 1:4) {
  test[i] <- binom.test(x[i], n, p[i], alternative = "two.sided", conf.level = 0.95)$p.value
}

test
[1] 6.621447e-111  1.801758e-92  3.467288e-82  2.442975e-81
```